# Is it possible to create a double slit experiment that can predict when photons have 'likely' passed through the slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, double-slit-experiment

This [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/245521/is-it-possible-to-determine-the-slit-a-photon-went-through-in-the-double-slit-ex) asked:Is it possible to determine the slit a photon went through in the double slit experiment by measuring its flight time?

My question is similar, but doesn't require such detailed information. I'm more interested in whether it's possible to say: at time $t_1$, there's a 99/100 chance that a photon will be somewhere between the slits and detecting screen.

Comment: A search term that will help is "weak measurement". There are even a number of question on the site about it.